# Why themove item showing the following error in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$_SourcePath = "H:\*"
$_DestinationPath = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Myfolder"



Move-item –path $_SourcePath –destination $_DestinationPath
```

> Move-item : Cannot remove item H:\Documents$RECYCLE.BIN: You do not
> have sufficient access rights to  perform this operation. At line:5
> char:1
>
> - Move-item –path $_SourcePath –destination $_DestinationPath
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (H:\Documents\$RECYCLE.BIN:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOExc
>   ```
>
> eption
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemC
> ommand

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot move it as it is a system folder. I tried to remove my own $recycle.bin on my home folder on a network path and got the a little bit mor informative message in:

```
You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation or the item is hidden, system, or read only.
```